# How to support bangla font in a webview while developing Android software

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a html file in a webView that contains Bangla sentences.But I'm having trouble to do this.Web page is showing, But the fonts or the sentences are not showing.
My code is here...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.physics_1st_chap1);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewc1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mathscribe/vector.html");



}
```

Answer (score 0):

asset/demo.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            /** Specify a font named "MyFont",
            and specify the URL where it can be found: */
            @font-face {
                font-family: "MyFont";
                 <!-- you can set Custom font here -->
                src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/BLKCHCRY.TTF');
            }
            h3 { font-family:"MyFont"}  
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Welcome to CustomFont Demo
    </h3>
</body>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting reference to WebView of the activity_main layout
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // Loading an html page into webview
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry ! Still having problem in loading the demo.html file which contains bangla sentences.